# Use ArcGIS Server REST geoprocessing service from the client without ArcGIS Web API's or ArcObjects

Tags: arcgis-server, rest, arcgis-rest-api

I'm checking to see if anyone knows how to execute and read the response from a custom Geoprocessor published on an ArcGIS Server as a REST web service without the use of ArcObjects or an ArcGIS web API on the client side.

I've built a custom geoprocessor service and successfully published it to ArcGIS server as a web service.  The service takes standard .Net objects as inputs and returns the same as outputs so there is no need for any ArcObjects on the client side.  I simply want to execute the REST web service by using standard .Net tools like `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` and `System.Net.HttpWebResponse` classes similar to what is [shown here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/497123/How-to-make-REST-requests-with-Csharp).

I've used the ArcGIS Server services with ArcGIS Web API's in the past, but doing it this way is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to refer to the [ArcGIS REST API docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html) to see how to make your requests. This would also apply to your custom geoprocessing service.

I basically do just pass the request through WebRequest in .NET and do any tweaking as needed. A simple version may look something like this.

```
public object Get(string name)
{
    string query = "where=NAME LIKE '%" + name.ToUpper() + "%'&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&returnDistinctValues=true&f=json";
    var request = WebRequest.Create(serviceURL + query);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "GET";
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    var stream = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    var o = Json.Decode(stream.ReadToEnd());
    response.Close();
    return o;
}
```

Once you have the request, you can parse the results into your own objects if you want and work with them from there.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the code sample.  Let me see if it will get me where I need to be.

Comment: After several other issues, I finally got something working.  Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Any idea on how to handle the completeCallback and/or statusCallback on the geoprocessor from the client when using it this way?

Comment: OK - to check on the job status when using the REST services this way I found [this link](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/analysis/api-reference/checking-job-status.htm) on the ArcGIS REST API: Spatial Analysis Service very helpful.